# Difference between two integrator circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, feedback, integrator

What is the difference between the two integrator circuits? They are used in an amplifier with feedback. There's heaps of information online about the one on the right but not so much about the one on the left.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the complete circuit and the component values, it is impossible to provide an answer. Depending on what is applied to "Feedback" and how I choose the component values, I can make both circuits do lots of things. If for example, if feedback connects straight to output and R3 and R7 have low value, both circuits are voltage buffers. Also these are not pure integrators as then I expect R2 and R6 not to be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that the feedback and input pins are equivalent, they both have a resistive input into the summing node of the opamp. So whatever the opamp does, it does to the scaled sum of the input and the feedback signals, the scaling being set by the respective resistors.

Neither of these circuits is an integrator. An integrator would have a simple capacitor feedback without R2 or R6. However, for much of the frequency range, their response is mostly integrator-like, falling by 20dB per octave, with a 90 degree phase shift, when the capacitor is dominating the response.

So when is the capacitor not dominating the response? When the impedance is dominated by the resistor.

For the lefthand circuit, that's at high frequency. The gain will stop falling, and become flat above frequencies where C1 impedance falls below R2. As C1 cannot conduct DC, there needs to be some other path for DC feedback from output to input so that the output doesn't ramp off to a rail.

For the righthand circuit, it's at low frequency. The gain will stop rising and become flat below frequencies where C2 impedance rises above R6. Note this includes DC. This configuration is often used down to a very low frequency, with DC stability is ensured by R6.

Comment: I agree to everything you wrote. But the questioner (dos584) should know that neither R2 nor R6 are required if the circuit is part of an overall feedback loop, which contains any kind of dc path (amplifiers and/or resistive circuits) between the integrators output node and the node called "feedback".

Answer (score 1):

In fact, both circuits do NOT integrate. But this is no surprise because there is no IDEAL intergating circuit.

(1) However, the most left (first) circuit will not work at all becaus it has no DC feedback and, hence, no stable DC operating point. Immediately after power switch-on the output will go into saturation. The capacitor is continuously loaded by the DC ouput voltage caused by the unavoidable offset.

(2) The most right (second) circuit is a first order lowpass, which - however - is used as an integrating circuit for frequencies far above the 3dB corner frequency of this lowpass. The resistor R6 is necessary for a stable and fixed DC operating point (it allows a fixed dc gain Adc=-R6/R5 resp Adc=-R6/R7.

(3) The situation is different, when one of the circuits is used as a block within an overall negative DC feedback loop. In this case, neither the resistor R2 nor R6 is required. In this case both circuits are identical.

Answer (score -1):

The left circuit has a ZERO in the frequency response; this may be useful in a PID controller; I've used these circuits in Phase Locked Loops where pre-tuning, or Local Oscillator band-selection, required alteration of a conventional loop into a parallel feedback design for adequate Degree Of Freedom in achieving phase noise floors.

Comment: Why the downvote?